# Error when running a command as part of a script but not when ran individually

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm getting the following error when i run the command as part of the script or during debugging in both the Powershell ISE and Powershell terminal. I am running as administrator in both.

```
Rename-Item -Path IIS:\AppPools\webdba2 -NewName WEBDBA
```

> Rename-Item : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less
>   than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

The actual code in powershell is

```
Rename-Item -Path "IIS:\Sites\$CurrentWebsiteName" -NewName $OrgUrl
```

Now running with the variables or hard coded works outside of the script. I'm running it in a try catch statement.

Script:

```
$MassSiteData = Import-Csv $strPath -Header url,apppool,shorturl 
$intRowMax = $MassSiteData.count
$intRow = 0

ForEach($WebSite in $MassSiteData) 
{
    $intRow++

    $OrgAppPool = $WebSite.apppool
    $OrgUrl = $WebSite.url
    $OrgShortUrl = $WebSite.shorturl

    $AppPoolSearchVar = $WebSite.apppool + "*"
    $ShortUrlSearchVar = $WebSite.shorturl + "*"

    [Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")

    $sm = New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager 
    $site = Get-Website | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $ShortUrlSearchVar}
    $CurrentWebsiteName = $site.Name 
    $CurrentWebPath = $site.PhysicalPath

    $CurrentAppPool = ($sm.ApplicationPools | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $AppPoolSearchVar}).Name
    $CurrentAppPath = split-path -parent $CurrentWebPath

    try {
        ##Rename AppPool
        Rename-Item -Path "IIS:\AppPools\$CurrentAppPool" -NewName $OrgAppPool
        $logMsg = "Renamed App Pool to $OrgAppPool"
        Write-Host "Renamed App Pool to $OrgAppPool"
        $logMsg | Out-File $logfilelocation -Append
    } catch {
        $logMsg = "App Pool didnt need updated"
        write-host "App Pool Errored out. Most likely didnt need updated"
        $logMsg | Out-File $logfilelocation -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more of the script to your question? This error generally appears when you are iterating through a collection using `ForEach-Object` or incorrectly setting your variable type to `@()`.

Comment: Added more to the script.

Comment: Looks to me that `$CurrentAppPool = ($sm.ApplicationPools | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $AppPoolSearchVar}).Name` returns an array of AppPool names. In that case, decide what to do: loop through with `foreach()`, just rename the first one `$CurrentAppPool[0]` or change the `-like` operator to `eq`

Comment: Its only returning a single app pool. 

PS C:\Windows\system32> ($sm.ApplicationPools | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $AppPoolSearchVar}).Name__________

Returns: webdba2